# How to add an optionnal field using nested serializers

Tags: django-rest-framework, nested

I want the description field of milestones to be only in ProjectDetailSerializer

```
class Milestone(models.Model):
    """Create sections for project"""

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    hierarchycal_order = models.IntegerField()
    order = models.IntegerField()
                ...
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='milestones',
        null=True
    )
```

```
class MilestoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for milestones of projects"""

    class Meta:
        model = Milestone
        fields = ['title', 'hierarchycal_order', 'order']
        read_only_fields = ['id']
```

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for projects"""
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    milestones = MilestoneSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'time_hours', 'link', 'tags', 'milestones']
```

It would be like the + ['description'] but for the description of the milestones,
but maybe it s implemented in a total different way i don't know

```
class ProjectDetailSerializer(ProjectSerializer):
    """Serializer for project detail view."""

    class Meta(ProjectSerializer.Meta):

        fields = ProjectSerializer.Meta.fields + ['description'] # + ['milestones.description']
```

i tried :

```
+ ['milestones.description]
+ [description, {'milestones': description}]
+ [{'milestones':'description'}]
```

maybe i should add the field in MilestoneSerializer and remove it in ProjectSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_flex_fields import FlexFieldsModelSerializer
```

...

```
class MilestoneSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Milestone
        fields = ['title', 
            'hierarchycal_order', 'order', 'description']
        read_only_fields = ['id']
```

...

```
class ProjectSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for projects"""
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    milestones = MilestoneSerializer(
        many=True,
        required=False,
        fields=['title', 'hierarchycal_order', 'order']
    )
```

...

```
class ProjectDetailSerializer(ProjectSerializer):
    """Serializer for project detail view."""
    milestones = MilestoneSerializer(
        many=True,
        required=False,
        fields=['title', 'hierarchycal_order', 'order', 'description']
    )

    class Meta(ProjectSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ProjectSerializer.Meta.fields + ['description']
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).